# Get the word under cursor with Sublime

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Let's say we have this text in Sublime Text, and that we have the cursor over `f`:

```
hello blabla.foo youhou
```

**I'd like to find a command to get `blabla.foo`**, i.e.

- search the previous whitespace () occurence before cursor
- search the next whitespace occurence after cursor
- get the string between these two occurences

---

It seems that `view.word(...)` doesn't work:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class MyCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        for region in self.view.sel():
            print self.view.substr(self.view.word(region))
```

because the returned word is `foo`. How to get the full word instead (i.e. `blabla.foo`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `.` (full stop) is recognized as word separator.
In your Sublime settings you can remove the `.` (full stop) from the list of word separators:

Default: ``` "word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}``~?", ```
Change to: ``` "word_separators": "/\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{``~?", ```

After that change `view.word(...)` should return `blabla.foo`.