# Sublime Plugin - Show possible arguments for a selected function like intellisense

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to write a plugin and was wondering if there's a way to show the autocompletions based on what what specifically selected. In this language, functions don't have all the arguments needed so having it autocomplete every single argument is not a good idea.

For example, say the user selects a command called `[&Command]` from autocomplete, I'd want autocomplete to reappear after selecting it and show all the possible arguments the command can take. One possible command is `[&Command func="Show"]` but another could be `[&Command demo="Create" type="Id"]` (not actual commands, this is just an example)

In a nutshell, is there a way to get what the user selected from autocomplete and then use it to force autocomplete to appear and change what autocompletions are shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone wants to know the solution I came up with so far (some minor issues still happen like requiring to press space twice to trigger the autocomplete):

```
class ScriptListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):


commands = [
    '&Command1',
    '&Command2'
]

Command1_completions = [
    'param1=',
    'param2='
]

Command2_completions = [
    'param1=',
    'param2='
]

last_word = ""
current_row = ""

def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
    if not view.match_selector(locations[0], "source.script"):
        return None

    if self.last_word == self.commands[0] or self.commands[0] in self.current_row:
        return self._remove_known_arguments(self.Command1_completions)
    elif self.last_word == self.commands[1] or self.commands[1] in self.current_row:
        return self._remove_known_arguments(self.Command2_completions)
    else:
        return None

def on_modified(self, view):
    for region in view.sel():
        if (' ' in view.substr(view.word(region))):
            self.current_row = view.substr(view.line(view.sel()[0]))
            if any(command in self.current_row for command in self.commands):
                view.run_command("auto_complete")
        else:
            self.last_word = view.substr(view.word(region))

def on_selection_modified(self, view):
    #Get current row
    self.current_row = view.substr(view.line(view.sel()[0]))

def _remove_known_arguments(self, comp_list):
    for arg in comp_list:
        if (arg in self.current_row):
            comp_list.remove(arg)
    return comp_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there an [LSP server](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/implementors/servers/) for this language? If so, all you need to do is write a wrapper for it using the Sublime [LSP](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP) plugin. If not, it's going to be rather complex, as you'll need to be able to parse the source code of the language to determine what the potential arguments are. Take a look at the [source of the `Anaconda` plugin](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/) or the [`jedi`](https://pypi.org/project/jedi/) module to see how it's done for Python.

#### Edit

I realized that I didn't actually answer your question about getting and setting completion items. In the [API](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html), relevant classes to work with include [`sublime.CompletionList`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html#sublime.CompletionList), [`sublime.CompletionItem`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html#sublime.CompletionItem), and [`sublime.CompletionValue`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html#sublime.CompletionValue). You will also be interested in the [`sublime_plugin.EventListener.on_query_completions()`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener.on_query_completions) method and its `prefix` parameter. This method is also available in [`sublime_plugin.ViewEventListener`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.ViewEventListener.on_query_completions). You can get the word under the cursor(s) using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220186/get-the-word-under-cursor-with-sublime), as an example.

Comment: No LSP server, its the companies own scripting language

Comment: @CephDigital Hmm. Well, if the language is based on another language, *and* that other language has an LSP server, *and* you know the language the server is written in, you could probably start there for clues. Otherwise, if your language has introspection capabilities and AST tools, those could definitely be helpful. At the last resort, scan the source files for indicators that a function is being defined (like `def` in Python), then use regex to parse out the arguments.

Comment: @CephDigital I reread your post and realized I didn't answer the question as asked in the last sentence. Please see my edit.

Comment: Still brought some good info for me to use, thanks!